# Get record with the last date/time

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table layout. I want to get the record for 'USER1' with the latest date/time stamp.

```
comments_sk case_sk comments    create_user_id  create_date
1           68200   test 1        USER1           2/11/17 11:00
1           68200   test 2        USER1           2/4/17 14:54
1           68200   test 3        USER2           12/30/16 12:37
1           8200    test 4        USER2           12/14/16 14:23
1           68200   test 5        USER3           12/13/16 9:16
1           68200   test 6        USER2           12/8/16 10:38
1           68200   test 7        USER3           12/2/16 10:58
1           68200   test 8        USER2           12/1/16 11:21
1           68200   test 9        USER2           11/8/16 13:36
```

I have tried these queries but all records for USER1 are showing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar) AS comments, create_user_id, create_date
FROM         comments AS s
WHERE     (s.case_sk = 68200) AND (s.create_user_id = 'USER1') AND (s.create_date =
                          (SELECT     MAX(s1.create_date) AS cdate
                            FROM          comments AS s1
                            WHERE      (s1.comments_sk = s.comments_sk)))
GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar), create_user_id, create_date
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

```
SELECT     s.comments_sk, s.case_sk, max(CAST(s.comments AS varchar)) AS comments, s.create_user_id, s.create_date
FROM         comments AS s INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT    comments_sk, case_sk, max(CAST(comments AS varchar)) AS comments, create_user_id, MAX(create_date) AS cdate
                            FROM          comments
                            GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar), create_user_id, maint_user_id, maint_date, comment_type_sk) AS s1 ON 
                      s.case_sk = s1.case_sk AND s.create_date = s1.cdate
WHERE     (s.case_sk = 68200)
GROUP BY s.comments_sk, s.case_sk, CAST(s.comments AS varchar), s.create_user_id, s.create_date, s.comment_type_sk
HAVING      (s.create_user_id = 'USER1')
ORDER BY s.create_date DESC
```

```
SELECT     comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar) AS comments, create_user_id, max(create_date)
FROM         comments AS s
WHERE     EXISTS
                          (SELECT     comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar) AS comments, create_user_id, MAX(create_date) AS cdate
                            FROM          comments AS s1
                            WHERE      (s1.case_sk = s.case_sk) AND (s1.comments_sk = s.comments_sk)
                            GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar), create_user_id, maint_user_id, maint_date, comment_type_sk
                            HAVING      (s.create_date = MAX(s1.create_date))) AND (s.create_user_id = 'USER1') AND (s.case_sk = 68200)
GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar), create_user_id, create_date, comment_type_sk
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'Top 1' and descending order, you should be able to get what you want. Try this:

```
SELECT top 1 comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar) AS comments, create_user_id, create_date
FROM         comments AS s
WHERE     (s.case_sk = 68200) AND (s.create_user_id = 'USER1') 
GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar), create_user_id, create_date
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, I am suggesting that you use a **CTE** to get the latest comment for a user and then link it to the *comments* table to get the actual comment. This is an example of how the query can be written. Most probably you want to modify the `WHERE` clause and use parameters instead of the hard coded values:

```
; with _cte as (
    SELECT DISTINCT comments_sk, case_sk, create_user_id, Max(create_date) as lastCommentDate
    FROM         comments AS s
    WHERE     s.create_user_id = 'USER1'
    GROUP BY comments_sk, case_sk, create_user_id
)

SELECT  _cte.comments_sk, _cte.case_sk, CAST(comments AS varchar) AS comments, _cte.create_user_id, _cte.lastCommentDate
FROM    comments AS s
        inner join _cte on s.create_date = _cte.lastCommentDate and s.create_user_id = _cte.create_user_id and s.case_sk = _cte.case_sk
WHERE     (s.case_sk = 68200) AND (s.create_user_id = 'USER1')
```

Comment: Feryal, thanks for the feedback but top1 will not work since the query will be used against multiple case_sk. I just used 68200 as an example. I apologize for not mentioning in the original post.

Comment: Does the new query in the update section work for you?

Comment: yes, but only for a specific case. I was able to figure out. Thanks for your feedback.